# Why isn't my math right

Tags: c#, math, webrequest

I'm trying to make a simple tool in which you can track your invest with BTC. I have all the data a need to calculate everything but when comes to the exchange price changing my "investment total" doesn't change. Meaning when BTC goes up, my result of how much money I made stays the same almost and the same for when it goes down.

I have posted my code and tried a bunch of different solutions, including different types: floats, decimals, int's, doubles and it always turns out the same way. What am I missing?

[image]

EDIT - CODE:

```
namespace BTC_Profit_Projections
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }
        Core c = new Core();

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Enabled = true;
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var ExchangeRate = c.GrabBTCAmount();
            var AmountInBTC = (c.USDtoBTC(15000, ExchangeRate));
            var AmountAtMarket = (AmountInBTC * ExchangeRate);

            ListViewItem i = new ListViewItem("15000");
            i.SubItems.Add(AmountInBTC.ToString());
            i.SubItems.Add(AmountAtMarket.ToString());
            i.SubItems.Add(ExchangeRate.ToString());
            mainlist.Items.Add(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Core Class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace BTC_Profit_Projections
{
    class Core
    {

        public decimal GrabBTCAmount()
        {
            WebClient w = new WebClient();
            string btc = w.DownloadString("https://www.bitstamp.net/api/ticker/");

            int pos1 = btc.IndexOf("last", 0);
            int pos2 = btc.IndexOf(":", pos1);
            int pos3 = btc.IndexOf(",", pos2);

            return Convert.ToDecimal(btc.Substring(pos2 + 3, pos3 - pos2 - 4));

        }

        public decimal USDtoBTC(decimal money, decimal rate) 
        {
            return money / rate;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks correct to me. Can you highlight where is the wrong value?

Comment: Dont post pictures of code - paste the actual code.  And what does this have to do with `webrequest`?

Comment: [I downvoted because image of code sample](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode). Paste your code as actual text instead of image and include [mcve].

Comment: I included my code in the sample now, with a photo of my output just. The issue is I'm getting large increases in prices and TINY changes in my total revenue.

Comment: @Frank Can you highlight what is wrong?

Comment: @Frank, for this to be a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) we need not only code but also some example of wrong calculation that shows why you think something is wrong

Comment: I didn't down-vote, but it's mostly likely because you haven't given a solid statement of what your inputs are, what result you're getting, and **what you expect the result to be for the given input**.

Comment: Look at the data given in the image. You can see the BTC exchange price is changing by 5-10 dollars sometimes and my total rev. is staying the same pretty much.

Comment: Someone who has not read [ask] and/or not taken the [tour] ought not complain about downvotes or close votes

Comment: You don't have a total revenue column. You'd need your cost basis for that, wouldn't you? You just have a column that converts the amount of bitcoins back to dollars again, only with so much precision that you are seeing slight differences. To figure out your revenue, you need to know **how many bitcoins you originally purchased** (or what the exchange rate was at the time of purchase).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not clear why you expect this code to behave differently. Look at these lines:

```
        var ExchangeRate = c.GrabBTCAmount();
        var AmountInBTC = (c.USDtoBTC(15000, ExchangeRate));
        var AmountAtMarket = (AmountInBTC * ExchangeRate);
```

If I inline `USDtoBTC` and inline everything to calculate `AmountAtMarket` the formula would be

```
AmountAtMarket  = (15000 / ExchangeRate) * ExchangeRate
```

So you should always get `15000` with some rounding error.

The bug seems to be in the line where you calculate `AmountInBTC`. To calculate `AmountInBTC` you should divide your investment sum (I assume `15000`) by the exchange rate ***at the moment you did your investment*** rather than current exchange rate.

Comment: Can you expand further on this?

Comment: @Frank, Not sure I can unless you provide more details on what is unclear to you. Mathematically what you calculate as `AmountAtMarket` is just a constant `15000`. Because of limitations of how floating point numbers are implemented you get not exact value but also have some rounding error. Am I right that you made single investment? If so it means that in the real world `AmountInBTC` is just some single constant value and doesn't change when `ExchangeRate` fluctuates. You need to calculate that value by dividing sum of your investment by the exchange rate on the day/time of the investment.

Comment: So that would be `(15000 * AmountInBTC) / Exchange Rate` ?

Comment: @Frank, I don't know. What is `15000`? Is that sum in dollars of your investment? Is that price at which you bought your BTC? Is it something else? You don't provide enough details to give you a meaningful answer.

Comment: Or `((15000 * AmountInBTC) / ExchangeRate)) * 100` ? To give me how much (in dollars) it changes?

Comment: 15,000 is price in US dollars that is invested @ current exchange rate.

Comment: @Frank, assuming you did single investment, the formula should be `SumInDollarsOfTheInvestment / ExchangeRateAtTheTimeOfInvestment * CurrentExchangeRate`. Note that currently in your code there is no `ExchangeRateAtTheTimeOfInvestment` and without knowing it you can't calculate anything. Example: if you invested `$15k` when exchange rate was `10k $/BTC` and now rate is `16k $/BTC`, your current investment value is `15/10*16`  = `$24k`